# Управление пользователями windows server из cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, windows-server

Как с помощью командной строки отправить всем пользователям сообщение и спустя некоторое время завершить их сеанс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Получить список всех залогиненных пользователей консольной командой:

   query user

В списке видны их ID сеанса и статус активности.

2. Активным можно отправить сообщений по номеру сеанса (это первый параметр, предположим, что он равен 1):

   msg 1 Bla-bla-bla

Сообщение дойдет ТОЛЬКО до активных, а не отключенных пользователей.
Чтобы отправить сообщение сразу всем сеансам активных пользователей, нужно вместо ID указать символ *

```
msg * Bl-Bla-bla
```

3. Завершить сеанс пользователя (по его ID) можно командой:

   logoff 1

Исходя из этих команд получаем бат-файл:

```
@msg * LOGOUT TIME!

@ping 127.0.0.1  -n 10 >nul

@for /f "skip=1 tokens=3," %%i in ('@query user') DO @if NOT "%%i"=="" logoff %%i
```